# Summing Top N categories in SQL with all others in "Other"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to categorize a data set where the description categories with the top 3 record counts would be summed as the top 3 and all others would be counted into an "other" category(I'm doing this for purposes of an SSRS report).  I used a window function to organize each category but I'm having difficult creating the final result.

```
     declare @t table(id int, description varchar(50))
     insert into @t values(123, 'Cardiac'),
                 (124, 'Cardiac'),
                 (125, 'Cardiac'),
                 (126, 'Cardiac'),
                 (222, 'Digestive'),
                 (223, 'Digestive'),
                 (224, 'Digestive'),
                 (225, 'Digestive'),
                 (226, 'Digestive'),
                 (333, 'Muscular'),
                 (334, 'Muscular'),
                 (335, 'Muscular'),
                 (336, 'Muscular'),
                 (444, 'Nose'),
                 (445, 'Nose'),
                 (446, 'Nose'),
                 (447, 'Nose'),
                 (448, 'Nose'),
                 (449, 'Nose'),
                 (555, 'Ear'),
                 (555, 'Ear'),
                 (666, 'Mouth')
```

I've written this so far:

```
    select *, row_number()over(partition by description order by id) as ranks
    from @t
    group by id, description
```

The result I'd like is this:

```
     Description   Count
       Nose          6
       Digestive     5
       Cardiac       4
       Muscular      4
       Other         3
```

I'm thinking it involves using a window function with a count(), but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select (case when seqnum <= 4 then description else 'Other' end), sum(cnt) as cnt
from (select description, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from @t
      group by description
     ) d
group by (case when seqnum <= 4 then description else 'Other' end)
order by min(seqnum);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error of "invalid column name 'cnt'.  I think it's due to the "order by cnt desc" in the window function of the derived table.

Comment: I think I got it.  I changed 'order by cnt' to 'order by count(*)

Answer (score 0):

Use window function `COUNT()`:

```
with 
  cte as (
    select distinct
      description, 
      count(*) over (partition by description) counter
    from @t
  ),
  top3 as (select top 3 with ties * from cte order by counter desc)  
select description, counter
from (
  select description, counter, 1 ord from top3
  union all
  select distinct 'Others', count(*) over (), 2
  from @t
  where description not in (select description from top3)
) t
order by ord, counter desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4838627e816002cc254095a64e7c0eed).
Results:

```
> description | counter
> :---------- | ------:
> Nose        |       6
> Digestive   |       5
> Cardiac     |       4
> Muscular    |       4
> Others      |       3
```

Answer (score 0):

Given how you appear to want to handle ties use rank() instead of row_number():

```
select description
, sum(cnt) as cnt
from (
    select case
        when rank() over(order by count(*) desc) <= 3 then description
        else 'Other' end as description
    , count(*) as cnt
    from @t
    group by description
)
group by description
```